# Angular 2 Auxiliary route works first time and not in subsequent clicks

Tags: angular, routes

I have defined lazy loaded routes and  auxiliary route as shown in the below code.

```
export const MainRoutes = [
    { path: '', component: WelcomeComponent }, 
    { path: 'Customer', loadChildren: 'Modules/CustomerModule#CustomerModule' },
    { path: 'Supplier', loadChildren: 'Modules/SupplierModule#SupplierModule' },
    {
        path: 'Help',
        outlet: 'helpoutlet',
        component: HelpComponent
    }
];
```

Below is the code where my other routes and auxillary routes are called.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/Supplier/Add']">Supplier</a> 
<a [routerLink]="['/Customer/Add']">Customer</a><br />
<a [routerLink]="[{outlets: {'helpoutlet': ['Help']}}]">Help</a>

        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <router-outlet name="helpoutlet"></router-outlet>
```

Below is code for supplier routes

```
export const SupplierRoutes = [
    {
        path: 'Add', component: SupplierComponent
    }
];
```

Below is code for Customer routes

```
export const CustomerRoutes = [
    {
        path: 'Add',
        component: CustomerComponent

    }    
];
```

When i first navigate to Supplier link and then to auxillary route ( help) it works first time. But after that when  i click on Customer and then auxillary route , it does not work. The other routes continue working.Auxillary routes just disappear from the screen.

My other routes are lazy loaded , is that issue ?. Stuck like a glue.

Comment: It seems like there is problem with auxillary route while navigating from one child route to other aux route. Can you please try to use `router.navigateUrl('yourUrl')`? Did you tried this without lazy loading?

Comment: Good suggestion @PankajParkar let me try it.

Comment: It did work with out lazy loading. Looks like its a bug https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15447 . Phiss

Comment: Cool finding sir.. but I guess you can proceed by using `navigateToUrl`, does that work for you?

Comment: Already tried navigate using code. Its a bug  and the fix is here https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/12412 , i migrated to Angular 4 my project and everything is ok now.

Answer (score 3):

i tried in my local environment and it works well. I think the problem is with your lazy loading modules, your are not loading the routes in the module properly. I am using lazy loading and i think that is not the issue. I am attaching my code, please take a look.

app.routes.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthUserGuard, ClientSaaSUserGuard } from './app.guards';
import { Routes, RouterModule, CanActivate,  } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent, LoginComponent, RegistrationComponent, PageNotFoundComponent } from './components/common';

const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'register', component: RegistrationComponent},
    { path: 'consult', loadChildren:'./modules/consult/consult.module#PmConsultingModule'},
    { path: 'saas', loadChildren:'./modules/saas/saas.module#SaasModule'},
    { path: 'logAux', component: LoginComponent, outlet: 'topNav' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class MainRoutesModule {};
```

app.component.html

```
<a [routerLink]="['register']">Register</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/consult']">Consult</a>
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { 'topNav': ['logAux'] } }]">Aux</a>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div style="color: green; margin-top: 1rem;">topNav bar:</div>
<div style="border: 2px solid blue; padding: 1rem;">
    <router-outlet name="topNav"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

consult.routes.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, CanActivate,  } from '@angular/router';
import { PMConsultUserGuard, AdminUserGuard } from './../../app.guards';
import { PMDashboardComponent } from './index';
import { PmConsultingComponent } from './consult.component' ;

const PMCONSULTING_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: PmConsultingComponent, children: [
        { path: 'admin', component: PMDashboardComponent , canActivate: [AdminUserGuard] },
        { path: 'pm', component: PMDashboardComponent , canActivate: [PMConsultUserGuard] }
    ]},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(PMCONSULTING_ROUTES)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class PMConsultingRoutesModule {};
```

Comment: interesting let me have a detail look thanks for responding.

Comment: Prudhvi sir which version of Angular you have 2 or 4.

Comment: Prudhvi sir i have also updated my routing code of lazy loading. They are just single path. When i migrated to angular  4 as it is. It started working.

Comment: I am using angular 2.

Comment: In your code i didn't saw any flaws. If you provide me complete code snippets of your work, i will try in my machine and let you know.

Comment: I will provide the plunker today evening thanks for all help.